# For a software application 'back' button title. What makes more sense in Spanish?

Tags: comparación-de-idiomas

For a software application 'back' button title.  What makes more sense in Spanish?  I've seen 'regresar', 'atras', 'retorno'

Answer (score 1):

You can look at an article about how to include a back button in HTML.
This article is a Spanish version of an English article.  They use
"retroceso" as a general descriptive, and "Regresar!"  as the title for the button.

[view article](https://mejorsoftware.info/blog/como-crear-un-boton-de-retroceso-html/#:%7E:text=Aqu%C3%AD%2C%20creamos%20el%20bot%C3%B3n%20usando%20un%20elemento%20%3Cform%3E%2C,value%20%3D%20%22%C2%A1Regresar%21%22%20onclick%20%3D%20%22history.back%20%28%29%22%3E%20%3C%2Fform%3E)

Also, note the following description of the ALT+LeftArrow combination in Microsoft documentation in Spanish.

Retroceso ( Retroceso ) o Alt + Flecha izquierda : para volver a la página anterior.

Comment: Hola, estás confundiendo términos. Se dice 'volver', 'atrás', 'regresar' pero no se dice 'retroceso' por ser el equivalente a *backspace*.

Comment: Lo copié de Microsoft.